# how to get multidimantional array in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' =>'BlackBerry Leather Smart Flip Case for BlackBerry PRIV',
    'product_type' => 'Mobile',
    'product_image' => array(
        0 => array(
            'product_id' => 1,
            'image_src'=> 'https://22198_grande.jpg',
            'variant_ids' => 11
        )
    ),
    'product_variant' => array(
        0 => array(
            'product_id' => 1,
            'image_id' => 21,
            'title' => "BlackBerry Leather Smart Flip Case for BlackBerry PRIV/black",
            'price' => 250
        )
    )
);
```

I want to change this array to associative array format

```
id=>1;
title=>BlackBerry Leather Smart Flip Case for BlackBerry PRIV;
product_type=>Mobile;
product_id=>1;
image_src=>https://22198_grande.jpg;
variant_ids=>11;
product_id=>1;
image_id=>21;
title=>BlackBerry Leather Smart Flip Case for BlackBerry PRIV/black;
price=>250
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Why not write some code to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel map function for this

```
$multiplied = $schoolkids->map(function ($kids) {
$test = $kids;
$temp = collect($kids->toArray());
return $temp->except(['id','class_id','org_id','section_id','parent_id', 'parent_info', 'class_name', 'classes', 'org_detail'])->merge($kids->orgDetail->toArray())->merge($kids->parentInfo->toArray())->merge($kids->classes->toArray());
});
```

$multiplied is the main query Kids is the first array function and if you want to remove some ids from array than use except function